# How to change display of solved equations results in matlab

Tags: matlab

When I solved system of three equations I got e.g.:

```
ans =

(220187671*1019780050779217710933721438668552804739490^(1/2))/130153889126365944306728960 - 2474730277849696199777672339/3425102345430682744913920
 - (220187671*1019780050779217710933721438668552804739490^(1/2))/130153889126365944306728960 - 2474730277849696199777672339/3425102345430682744913920
```

How can I change this result to result with accuracy of 3 places after dot? for example:

```
ans = 123.123
```

Comment: Why do you have an output like that? Are you using symbolic notations ('sym')?

Answer (score 1):

```
vpa(variable,3)
```

This will display 'variable' with 3 decimal digit accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a regular `double`:

```
format short
D = double(variable)
```

then use any kind of printing you like, for example, 3 digits:

```
fprintf('%.3f\n', D)
```