# Round-off numbers in symbolic expression

Tags: matlab, precision

I have a 1*1 vector created with a symbol in Matlab. Because of the symbol (t) all values are converted to integers such as

```
(142731759660517923771*exp(t))/2814749767106560000 - 
    (2384496775230702879947559372750244401*exp(2*t)) / 30948500982134506872478105600000000
```

But I want this expression as `50.7085*exp(t)- 77.0472*exp(2*t)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change display of solved equations results in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385764/how-to-change-display-of-solved-equations-results-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vpa` as like this:

```
 expression = (142731759660517923771*exp(t))/2814749767106560000 - 
  (2384496775230702879947559372750244401*exp(2*t)) 
      /30948500982134506872478105600000000;
 vpa(expression, 4);
```

See details of usage from the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html).

Comment: @Vipin You can accept this solution as an answer to get 2 points